# Datomic Clojure API: Semantics of t->tx?

Tags: clojure, datomic

I do not understand the meaning of the `datomic.api/t->tx`, which accepts a t value and returns a transaction id.

Is not the t value a property of the database incremented at each transaction ? If so, how could a transaction number be derived from it independently of any database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transaction Data (tx) is an Entity with an id. t is not the id, but there is an efficient mechanism to discover the t of a tx and for a tx the t. Effectively this means that you can look up transactions in a time range efficiently.

t is indeed a value indicating the order in which transactions occur, though I would not call it a property of the database or speculate on how it is calculated as it is not defined and could change. There is no defined term "transaction number", but I think you are asking how could one create a strictly increasing number without a database property. One answer is to use a clock, and prevent more than one transaction per tick. In any case, it isn't an implementation detail that we need to know in order to use the system.

The [glossary](http://docs.datomic.com/glossary.html#t) provides these definitions which I think are helpful:

t
A point in time in a database. Every transaction is assigned a numeric t value greater than any previous t in the database, and all processes see a consistent succession of ts. A transaction value t can be converted to a tx id with Peer.toTx.

tx
An entity representing a transaction. Every datom in a Datomic database includes the tx that created it, allowing recovery of the entire history of the database. Transactions are automatically associated with wall-clock time, but are otherwise ordinary entities. In particular, application code can make additional assertions about transactions. A tx entity id can be converted to a transaction t with Peer.toT.